# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \tan^2(3x)/x^2$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can anyone help me see how to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan^2 (3x)}{x^2}$$

Please, tell how can I solve it, I just have entered Calculus I, but if you can don't tell the final answer.

Thank you, :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply use *equivalents*: $\;\tan u\sim_0u$,  hence
$$\frac{\tan^23x}{x^2}\sim_0\frac{(3x)^2}{x^2}=9.$$

Answer (score 4):

Using the known limit 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1
$$
yields
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan^2(3x)}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}\right)^2\left(\frac{3}{\cos(3x)}\right)^2=
1^2\cdot\left(\frac{3}{\cos(0)}\right)^2=9
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\frac{\tan^2(3x)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{\cos^2 (3x)}\left(\frac{3\sin 3x}{3x}\right)^2=\frac{9}{\cos^2(3x)}\left(\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}\right)^2$$
and use your knowledge of well-known limits and limit laws namely $$\lim_{u \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin u}{u}=1.$$